# TextField in Material UI won't display label after selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textview, material-ui, dropdown

TextField of Material UI won't display the label after I select. However the state and value is updated correctly. I have already put `{option.label}`but it won't display. Anyone can help?
This is my text field.

```
<TextField
        id="standard-select-currency"
        select
        fullWidth
        label="Filter By"
        defaultValue= "lala"
        InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            style: { color: '#fff' }
        }}
        margin="normal"
        value={props.filter}
        onChange={props.handleChange('filter')}
      >
        {currencies.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
```

This is my currency

```
const currencies = [
  {
    value: 'USD',
    label: 'usd',
  },
  {
    value: 'EUR',
    label: 'eur',
  },
  {
    value: 'BTC',
    label: 'btc',
  },
  {
    value: 'JPY',
    label: 'jpy',
  },
];
```

The drop downlist is worked correctly and the state of react is updated.
[image]

But the label won't display after the selection
[image]

This is the
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/thirsty-ramanujan-ckgdt) I created for this case.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a demo of the selector.

Because it seems to be a problem with the value of the selector.

Comment: Please share a CodeSandbox that reproduces your problem. Here is a starting point with the code you have provided so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/currency-select-oe4rm (but it does not demonstrate your issue).

Comment: @fg93 I have created a demo for this case

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have shared the CodeSandbox for this case

Comment: Your sandbox doesn't work for me. It briefly displays a map and then displays an "Oops! Something went wrong." message and there are numerous console errors.

Comment: @RyanCogswell the map is not issue, is just no api key only,but the selector below the map is the issue

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have edited the sandbox to remove some error. After you select the option,you can see it printed in console. The state of react is updated correctly. However, it just won't display in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying `value={props.filter}` on your `TextField`, but you aren't specifying a `filter` prop to `MyMapComponent`.

If you change:

```
  render() {
    //console.log("render::::::::::::::::::::");
    return (
      <MyMapComponent
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
```

to add `filter={this.state.filter}` as follows:

```
  render() {
    //console.log("render::::::::::::::::::::");
    return (
      <MyMapComponent
        filter={this.state.filter}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
```

then it works.

[image: Edit Map filter]

Comment: It is a simple mistake. I keep debugging text field part but never notice this part.